# how to set autocommit = 1 in a sqlalchemy.engine.Connection

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

In sqlalchemy, I make the connection:

```
 conn = engine.connect()
```

I found this will set autocommit = 0 in my mysqld log.
Now I want to set autocommit = 1 because I do not want to query in a transaction.

Is there a way to do this?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

From [The SQLAlchemy documentation: Understanding autocommit](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/core/connections.html#understanding-autocommit)

```
conn = engine.connect()
conn.execute("INSERT INTO users VALUES (1, 'john')")  # autocommits
```

The “autocommit” feature is only in effect when no `Transaction` has otherwise been declared. This means the feature is not generally used with the ORM, as the `Session` object by default always maintains an ongoing `Transaction`.

Full control of the “autocommit” behavior is available using the generative `Connection.execution_options()` method provided on `Connection`, `Engine`, `Executable`, using the “autocommit” flag which will turn on or off the autocommit for the selected scope. For example, a `text()` construct representing a stored procedure that commits might use it so that a SELECT statement will issue a COMMIT:

```
engine.execute(text("SELECT my_mutating_procedure()").execution_options(autocommit=True))
```

Comment: This does work when i want to commit right after the sql statement.But this will still query for the master sql-server, I want to set autocommit = 1 before the sql statement.Because if does so, this sql will query for the slave mysql-server.So How to do?I have read the link you given ,still no answer.

Answer (score 12):

What is your [dialect](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/core/engines.html#mysql) for mysql connection?

You can set the `autocommit` to `True` to solve the problem, like this `mysql+mysqldb://user:password@host:port/db?charset=foo&autocommit=true`

Comment: So does your answer means:  if I do not set `autocommit=true` in url of the database, by default, the autocommit value is false?

Answer (score 10):

You can use this:

```
from sqlalchemy.sql import text

engine = create_engine(host, user, password, dbname)
engine.execute(text(sql).execution_options(autocommit=True))
```

Answer (score 4):

I might be little late here, but for fox who is using sqlalchemy >= 2.0.*, above solution might not work as it did not work for me.

So, I went through the official documentation, and below solution worked for me.

```
from sqlalchemy import create_engine
db_engine = create_engine(database_uri, isolation_level="AUTOCOMMIT")
```

Above code works if you want to set autocommit at the engine level.
But if you want use autocommit for a particular query then you can use below -

```
with engine.connect().execution_options(isolation_level="AUTOCOMMIT") as connection:
    with connection.begin():
        connection.execute("<statement>")
```

[Official Documentation](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/20/core/connections.html)

Answer (score 3):

In case you're configuring sqlalchemy for a python application using flask / django, you can create the engine like this:

```
# Configure the SqlAlchemy part of the app instance
app.config['SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI'] = conn_url


session_options = {
    'autocommit': True
}

# Create the SqlAlchemy db instance
db = SQLAlchemy(app, session_options=session_options)
```

Answer (score 0):

This can be done using the `autocommit` option in the `execution_option()` method:

```
engine.execute("UPDATE table SET field1 = 'test'").execution_options(autocommit=True))
```

This information is available within the [documentation](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/core/connections.html#understanding-autocommit) on Autocommit

Comment: This does work when i want to commit right after the sql statement.But this will still query for the master sql-server, I want to set autocommit = 1 before the sql statement.Because if does so, this sql will query for the slave mysql-server.So How to do?I have read the link you given ,still no answer