# Executing a postgresql query with plpg-sql from sqlalchemy

Tags: python, postgresql, sqlalchemy, plpgsql

I can't find examples using **plpg-sql in raw SQL to be executed by sqlAlchemy** these were the closest but no plpg-sql:

[How to execute raw SQL in Flask-SQLAlchemy app](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17972020/how-to-execute-raw-sql-in-flask-sqlalchemy-app/)
[how to set autocommit = 1 in a sqlalchemy.engine.Connection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26717790/how-to-set-autocommit-1-in-a-sqlalchemy-engine-connection)

I've done research and I'm not sure if this is possible. I'm trying to either INSERT or UPDATE a record and there is no error. It must fail silently because there's no record created/updated in the database and I've explicitly set `AutoCommit=True`.

Python:

```
engine = db.create_engine(connstr, pool_size=20, max_overflow=0)
Session = scoped_session(sessionmaker(bind=engine, autocommit=True))
s = Session()

query = """DO $$
declare
ppllastActivity date;
percComplete numeric;
begin
select lastactivity into ppllastActivity FROM feeds WHERE email = :e and courseName=:c and provider = :prov;
IF COALESCE (ppllastActivity, '1900-01-01') = '1900-01-01' THEN
INSERT INTO feeds (email, courseName, completedratio, lastActivity, provider) VALUES (:e, :c, :p, :l, :prov);
ELSEIF ppllastActivity < :l THEN
UPDATE feeds set completedratio = :p,lastActivity = :l WHERE email = :e and courseName = :c and provider = :prov;
END if;
end; $$"""

params = {'e' : item.get('email').replace("'", "''").lower(), 'c' : item.get('courseName').replace("'", "''"), 'p' : item.get('progress'), 'l' : item.get('lastActivity'),'prov' : "ACG" }
result = s.execute(text(query),params)
```

I'm unable to troubleshoot since it doesn't give me any errors. Am I going down the wrong path? Should I just use `psql.exe` or can you do **plpg-sql in raw SQL with sqlAlchemy?**

Answer (score 0):

While typing this question up I found a solution or a bug.

The `automcommit=True` doesn't work, you have to begin a transaction:

```
with s.begin():
     result = s.execute(text(query),params)
```